# Reg Silverlight XAP location

Tags: silverlight

Where on the client side will all the XAP files will be downloaded to and used by the Silverlight runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are downloaded to a temp internet folder (like other internet content). You should not need to know/care as all access is via relative path or assembly references.